# Nested gridview closes when trying to edit or click on a checkbox

Tags: asp.net

My script:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../img/minus.png");
        $(this).next().next().val(1);
    });

    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../img/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        $(this).next().next().val("");
    });

    $(function () {
        $("[id*=IsExpanded]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $("[id*=childpanel]", $(this).closest("tr")).html() + "</td></tr>")
                $("[src*=plus]", $(this).closest("tr")).attr("src", "../img/minus.png");
            }
        });
    });
}

function Check_Click(objRef) {
    //Get the Row based on checkbox
    var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;

    //Get the reference of GridView
    var GridView = row.parentNode;

    //Get all input elements in Gridview
    var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        //The First element is the Header Checkbox
        var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];

        //Based on all or none checkboxes
        //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
        var checked = true;

        if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
            if (!inputList[i].checked) {
                checked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    headerCheckBox.checked = checked;        
}

function checkAll(objRef) {
    var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
        var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;

        if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
            if (objRef.checked) {
                inputList[i].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                inputList[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

My code:

```
<body style="background-color: White">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <ul class="topnav">
                <li>
                    <img src="https://cync.cinergycinemas.com/Images/Logo-15.png" alt="Logo" />
                </li>
                <li><a href="Adminhome.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="active" href="timecontrol.aspx">Employees<br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltotalemp" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="clockedIN.aspx">Clocked IN<br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblin" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Overtimegv.aspx">Overtime<br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblot" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="right"><a href="EID2.aspx">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <%-- Search box autocomplete extender using ajax --%>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="margin: 50px; text-align: center">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
                ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers"
                MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="0"
                TargetControlID="txtSearch"
                FirstRowSelected="True"
                CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
                CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList"
                CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
                CompletionListElementID="divwidth">
            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" /><br />
            <br />
            <%--   <input type="checkbox" id="Virtual_Keyboard" />Use Virtual Keyboard<br />--%>

            <%--  Gridview 1--%>

            <asp:GridView ID="MainGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataKeyNames="EID" HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataText="No Data Found. Try Again !" AllowPaging="True" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="MainGV_RowDataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField><%--Plus and minus buttons--%>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <img src="images/plus.png" style="cursor: pointer" />
                                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                    <%--Style="display: none"--%>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="childGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataKeyNames="EID" HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataText="No Data / Approved !" AllowPaging="True" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black">
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCheckall" onclick="checkAll(this)" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCheck" onclick="Check_Click(this)" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkCheck_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="EID" HeaderText="EID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobFunctionalTitle" HeaderText="JobFunctionalTitle" SortExpression="JobFunctionalTitle" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="IN_Time" HeaderText="IN_Time" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IN_Time"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="OUT_Time" HeaderText="OUT_Time" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OUT_Time"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department1" HeaderText="Department1" SortExpression="Department1"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Hours2" HeaderText="Hours2" SortExpression="Hours2"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes"></asp:BoundField>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EID" SortExpression="EID">
                            <%--<EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EID") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EID") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FullName" SortExpression="FullName">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FullName") %>' ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' ID="Label3"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>' ID="TextBox2"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>' ID="Label4"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JobFunctionalTitle" SortExpression="JobFunctionalTitle">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobFunctionalTitle") %>' ID="TextBox3"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobFunctionalTitle") %>' ID="Label5"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' ID="TextBox4"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' ID="Label6"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location_Name" SortExpression="Location_Name" Visible="false">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_Name") %>' ID="TextBox5"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_Name") %>' ID="Label7"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>        
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dev_prashanthConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Sp_timedeptdisplaytest1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HFLocnum" Name="Locnum" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" DefaultValue=""></asp:ControlParameter>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="NULL" Name="SearchText" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <%--<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DWHConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_EID_PIN]"></asp:SqlDataSource>--%>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFclkincount" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFtotalcount" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFLocnum" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFhours2" runat="server" />
            <script>
                function CreatePopup() {
                    return confirm("Do you confirm?");
                }
            </script>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFEID" runat="server" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

I need to have mu child gridview open when i select the checkbox. 
Please provide me some guidance.

Comment: I'd encourage you to create a smaller yet complete example. Don't just copy and paste your entire script. Spotting key chunks it's just more difficult this way and less people will be able to help you. Moreover, why don't you also tag JQuery and JavaScript since you are using them?

Comment: i will do that .

Comment: It a simple solution. I had to remove autopostback control from the checkbox...It works now. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Sometimes isolating the problem both mentally and physically leads, by itself, to the solution